# How to handle different .env files in Next?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, next.js

### What I want

I have created a new Next project, and I want to manage app behavior according to the `NODE_ENV` variable. The application must load different variables located in different .env files. eje. if I load `NODE_ENV=development`, the application should to load the variables located in `.env.development` file. What is the most efficient and safe way to do it in Next.

### What I have

#### package.json

In the `dev` script I pass the environment type:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  },
```

#### next.config.js

In the next configuration I load environment variables from correct .env file with `dotenv` library according to `NODE_ENV` variable pass in `dev`script in package.json.

```js
const path = require('path');
const withOffline = require('next-offline');
const webpack = require('webpack');

require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  ),
});

module.exports = withOffline({
  webpack: (config) => {
    // Returns environment variables as an object
    const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    // Allows you to create global constants which can be configured
    // at compile time, which in our case is our environment variables
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));
    return config;
  },
});
```

#### .env.development

```
TITLE=modo development
```

#### pages/index.js

```js
function HomePage() {
  return <div>{process.env.TITLE}</div>
}

export default HomePage
```

### With this aproach...

- This is the most efficient and safe way to handle diferent .env files in Next?

Comment: .env file must be loaded

Comment: what do you mean with this? im loading `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` file in `next.config.js`.

Comment: Use env file for getting config value

Comment: can u give an example with next please.

Answer (score 5):

`Nextjs` supports env by default without the need to use of `webpack.DefinePlugin`, just pass it to the `env` property of `next.config.js`.

So your code will become:

```js
// next.conf.js
const path = require('path');
const withOffline = require('next-offline');
const webpack = require('webpack');

require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  ),
});

module.exports = withOffline({
  env: {
    VAR_1: process.env.VAR_1
    ...
    // List all the variables that you want to expose to the client
  }
});
```

**PAY ATTENTION**: these env variables may be exposed to the client side (if you use them in one of your app page).

For example, if your `process.env` is containing secrets, and **by mistake** you are using one of them in one of the pages / components that are used by pages, they will be inside js files that are downloaded to the client side.

Since Next.js 9.4, there is a built in .env loading functionality, read about it here https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

Comment: Hi, felixmosh thanks for answering. I have two questions... if this aproach exposed my variables in frontend, how to manage my secrets? and what is the best way or best practices to manage diferents .env files.

Comment: As I wrote, only the `env` that is part of `next.conf` & **usage** of them in one of the pages will be exposed to client as well.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the @felixmosh that Nextjs supports env by default without the need to use of webpack.DefinePlugin, but...
**It may be seen as limited and confused while loading different configurations on each environment. You can see common problem here**
[enter link description here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12077)

You can solve this problem easily by following these small steps.

1. You’ll need to create a folder config on the root, with all environment stages you’d like to have. [image]
2. You can add the initial/common configuration in **default.js** like this.

   ````
     API: {
       API_URL: process.env.API_URL || '<http://localhost:4000>',
       ENDPOINT: '********',
       IS_MOCKING_ENABLED: false,
     },
   }```
   ````
3. Include above config files in the **Next.config.js** file by **publicRuntimeConfig**. If you’d like to have it just on the server-side use just **serverRuntimeConfig** like this.

   ````
   const APIConfig = config.get('API')
   const nextConfig = {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
     APIConfig,
    },
   }
   module.exports = nextConfig ```
   ````
4. Usage in any file.
5. ````
   const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()
   const APIConfig = publicRuntimeConfig.APIConfig
   [...] ```
   ````
6. Finally, in your **package.json**. You can inject the environment variables to load the appropriate configuration.
      `"start:local": "NODE_ENV=development run-p dev"`
7. **Reference**: [enter link description here](https://medium.com/guidesmiths-dev/handle-environment-configuration-in-next-js-9-b8dd22732ce1) for detail explanation.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with next13.4.x with app directory ...